# Using Materialpickerrender once pick and cancel button Title shows top in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]We are using visual material picker control in our app. If I select anything from the picker popup title shows the top and selected value below. If I click cancel from the picker popup title also shows top. It should be in the default state. How to resolve this xamarin forms android and ios?

internal class CustomMaterialPickerRenderer : MaterialPickerRenderer
{

}

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. With some screenshot?

Comment: I have added screenshot above

Comment: Even with screenshots, its not clear to me what you want it to look like. What should it show where it says "Picker"?  What should it show instead of "Cancel" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , do you want to make the title back to the default position when clicking on the cancel button ?

I test both on iOS and Android , the problem only occurs on Android side .

###### The solution for Android platform :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(MyRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace FormsApp.Droid
{
    class MyRenderer : MaterialPickerRenderer
    {
        Context _context;

        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;        
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);


            if(Element.IsFocused == false)
            {
                Control.EditText.ClearFocus();
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine. How to change the placeholder color and cursor color in ios renderer? I have changed the TintColor property in Placeholder and Cursor color in Control.AttributedPlaceholder, it is not changed the placeholder color and cursor color in ios

Comment: This is another problem , could you open a new thread to ask it? It is helpful to search for other people.

Comment: Hi @Colex i have another problem pls check  the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389057/system-formatexception-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-in-ios-xam