# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in IOS xamarin forms

Tags: string, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get a Formatexception with the message like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" on the follwing code in appcenter, for last one day i did not recreate and fix this issue. How to resolve this

DateTimeParse.ParseExact (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s, System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] format, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style)

DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, System.IFormatProvider provider)

```
string str = (string)value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime parsed = DateTime.MinValue.Date;

                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, DateString.strDMY, AppState.CultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out parsed))
                    {
                        if (parsed.Date.Year <= 1900)
                        {
                            return default(DateTime?);
                        }

                        return parsed;
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("/"))
                    {
                        if (str.Contains(":"))
                        {
                            return DateTime.ParseExact(str, DateString.SlashDMYHMS, AppState.CultureInfo);
                        }

                        return DateTime.ParseExact(str, DateString.SlashDMY, AppState.CultureInfo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        char[] splChar = { '.', '-', '_', ',' };
                        //VHC-8547
                        string valueformat = ". ";
                        if (str.Contains(valueformat))
                            str = str.Replace(valueformat, ".");
                        foreach (char spl in splChar)
                        {
                            if (str.Contains(spl.ToString()))
                            {
                                str = str.Replace(spl, '/');
                                if (str.Contains(":"))
                                {
                                    return DateTime.ParseExact(str, DateFormat.formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                                }

                                return DateTime.ParseExact(str, DateFormat.formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is the input string that is failing?

Comment: i dont know which input string is failing change region and language but still not recreate to which input string is failing

Comment: you need to catch the exception and log it so you can determine which inputs are causing the problem

Comment: Use debugger to figure out what is the input string and which line causes the error .

Comment: yeah thank u  for ur replies i figured out what input string is causes and also fixed, issue in slashDMY format that date format is dd/mm/yyyy for input string format is dd/mm/yy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it stands, it won't be helpful to anyone else. If there is any reason to keep the question open, then please add more details to the question, now that you know what the problem was. Or even better, add an answer below, showing the code snippet that worked.